# executing commands base on the order of the parameters

Tags: java, arraylist

I am building my own command line in java. I implemented all other commands . I want to try executing commands base on the order of the parameters for ex)

**command: (history Y C) ,command: (history C Y )**

(history Y) indicates print previous history number of commands of (Y) numbers and  (C) indicates clearing history commands.

so (history C Y) should clear history command first and print Y number of previous commands which would be null;

(history Y C) should print Y number of previous commands and then clear history commands.

How should i implement my code outputing results base on different order

i am splitting commands with " " (space) using split .

and this is what currently i got

```
    if (Split[0].equals("history")) {

         if (Split[1].equals("Y")) {
    int num = int parseint(command)
}
        if (Split[2].equals("C")) {
        " Then clear command"
}
}
```

from above code it is history Y C
how do i implement it as user choice to put in different order?

Comment: If you are reading the commands from the command line, then you should have an array of arguments from the parameter to the main method.  If you are parsing arbitrary text lines, the split idea gets complicated if you need to deal with quoted arguments.  Either way, you should just iterate across the resulting array of arguments and process them in order.

Answer (score 0):

The **main()** method of your application already accepts a String Array of commands from the command line (this is what the **args** parameter is for) but it does work differently depending upon how the command line arguments are provided. All command line arguments are considered as String Array of String objects whether those arguments are enclosed in quotation marks or not, for example:

If your compiled application is named: **MyApp.jar** and in the **main()** method we have some simple code to print the supplied Command Line arguments to the Console Window like:

```
public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

When you start your *compiled* application from let's say the Window's Command Prompt (cmd) as:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar Hi, my name is Johnny Walker
```

the Window will display:

```
Hi,
my
name
is
Johnny
Walker
```

You can see that each item supplied within the application's command line that is separated by one (***or more***) white-spaces is considered a separate command line argument. The **main()** method's arguments are always delimited with a white-space and not the typical comma (**,**). If however you want this entire string to be supplied to your application as a single Command Line argument then you need to enclose that entire string within quotation marks like this:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar "Hi, my name is Johnny Walker"
```

the Window will display:

```
Hi, my name is Johnny Walker
```

If you want to add more strings like this to the command line then they all need to be enclosed within quotation marks and separated with a white-space like this:

```
java -jar MyApp.jar "Hi, my name is Johnny Walker" "What's yours?" "Is it Bob?"
```

the Window will display:

```
Hi, my name is Johnny Walker
What's yours?
Is it Bob?
```

With the above now in mind I don't understand where your difficulty lies. If a User of your application is permitted to supply Command Line arguments in any order then let them do so. In my opinion, if there are a lot of different command line arguments that can be supplied then it makes better sense to allow them to be supplied in random order since it would be extremely difficult to remember an exact order they must be supplied. It's the application that needs to sort out the necessity of order after the arguments are received.

Since you want to create your own Command Line parser which would consist of a specific categorical application function or perhaps several specific categorical functions then you would need to instruct the User of exactly how the command line arguments are to be supplied to the application even allow for help context to be supplied with the use of the typical **/?** command line option, for example:

> There are four application categorical functions available that can be
>   accessed via the Command Line (History, Current, Modify, and Delete).
>   Each function along with their specific parameters must be supplied as
>   quoted strings. The functions and their respective parameters can be
>   supplied in any order, for example:
>
> **java -jar MyApp.jar "modify r l n" "history c r"**
>
> See application documentation for more information regarding Command 
>   Line or use this Command Line Option:
>
> **java -jar MyApp.jar /?**

A text based Help file for your application might look something like this:

```
MyApp Help:

There are four categorical application functions available that can be
accessed via the Command Line (History, Current, Modify, and Delete).
Each function along with their specific parameters must be supplied as
quoted strings. The functions and their respective parameters can be
supplied in any order, for example:

**java -jar MyApp.jar "modify r=12 l=hypo n=43.55" "history c r=12"**

Categorical Application Functions:

Letter case is optional.

------------------------------------------------------------------
HISTORY:

Display Record(s) History.

    C   Clear History.
    R=  Integer - Record Number (0 for all).
------------------------------------------------------------------

CURRENT:

Displays Current Record and Linked Record (if any).
Optionaly displays defined Variable Name.


    R=  Integer - Make Record Current (0 for No Record).
    L=  Integer - Linked To Record Number (0 for No Record).
    N   Optional- Also Display Variable Name.
------------------------------------------------------------------

MODIFY:

Modifies a Record Culture.

    R=  Integer - Record Number to Modify (0 for All).
    L=  Integer - Change Linked Record Number (0 for No 
                Record).
    N=  String  - Change Variable Name ("" for No Name).
------------------------------------------------------------------

DELETE:

Deletes a Record Culture and optionally removes any Links to it.
Records start from a value of 1. 

    R=  Integer - Record Number to Delete (0 for All).
    y=  Boolean - True to Remove related Links to this
                          record.
------------------------------------------------------------------   

See application documentation for more information regarding Command 
Line or use this Command Line Option:  

    java -jar MyApp.jar /?
```

and in the application's **main()** method for dealing with the Command Line options might look something like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Are there Command Line arguments?
        if (args.length > 0) {
            // Yes there is...
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                String[] suppliedArgs = args[i].toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
                // Function Categories
                switch (suppliedArgs[0]) {
                    case "/?":
                        doDisplayHelpInConsole();
                        System.exit(0);
                        break; 
                    case "history":
                        doHistory(suppliedArgs);
                        break;
                    case "current":
                        doCurrent(suppliedArgs);
                        break;
                    case "modify":
                        doModify(suppliedArgs);
                        break;
                    case "delete":
                        doDelete(suppliedArgs);
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Skipping Unknown Command Line Function (" + 
                                        suppliedArgs[0] + ")!");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("DONE!");
    }

    private static void doDisplayHelpInConsole() {
        // Prepare to read the MyAppHelp.txt file from 
        // the run location of MyApp.jar. This help text
        // file must reside in the same location the jar 
        // file resides in.
        File helpFile = new File(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + 
                                File.separator + "MyAppHelp.txt");
        if (!helpFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Help is not available - File Not Found!" + 
                System.lineSeparator() + "[" + helpFile.getAbsolutePath() + 
                "]");
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Try with Resources - Auto closes file.
            try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(helpFile)) {
                while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            // or use:  ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void doHistory(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            // Split the parameter name and its value
            String[] params = args[i].split(" = |= | =|=");
            // Process Parameters
            switch (params[0]) {
                case "c":
                    // Do what C is suppose to do...
                    clearHistory();                  // A method to clear history
                    System.out.println("History Cleared!");
                    break;
                case "r":
                    // Do what R is suppose to do... 
                    // Is the supplied value Numerical?
                    if (params[1].matches("\\d+")) {
                        // Yes...convert to integer
                        int recordNum = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                        displayRecord(recordNum);    // A method to display record
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unknown Assignment for History (" + 
                            params[0] + ")! History Failed!"); 
            }
        }
    }

    private static void doCurrent(String[] args) {
        int recordNum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            // Split the parameter name and its value
            String[] params = args[i].split(" = |= | =|=");
            // Process Parameters
            switch (params[0]) {
                case "r":
                    // Do what R is suppose to do...
                    // Is the supplied value Numerical?
                    if (params[1].matches("\\d+")) {
                        // Yes...convert to integer
                        recordNum = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                        displayRecord(recordNum);    // A method to display record
                    }
                    break;
                case "l":
                    // Do what L is suppose to do... 
                    // Is the supplied value Numerical?
                    if (params[1].matches("\\d+")) {
                        // Yes...convert to integer
                        int lRecordNum = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                        System.out.println("Linked to Record Number: " + lRecordNum);
                    }
                    break;
                case "n":
                    // Do what N is suppose to do... 
                    String varName = getVariableName(recordNum);
                    System.out.println("Variable Name: " + varName);
                    break;    
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unknown Assignment for Current (" + 
                            params[0] + ")! Current Failed!");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void doModify(String[] args) {
        int recordNum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            // Split the parameter name and its value
            String[] params = args[i].split(" = |= | =|=");
            // Process Parameters
            switch (params[0]) {
                case "r":
                    // Do what R is suppose to do...
                    // Is the supplied value Numerical?
                    if (params[1].matches("\\d+")) {
                        // Yes...convert to integer
                        recordNum = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                    }
                    break;
                case "l":
                    // Do what L is suppose to do... 
                    // Is the supplied value Numerical?
                    if (params[1].matches("\\d+")) {
                        // Yes...convert to integer
                        int lRecordNum = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                        System.out.println("Modifying Linked Record Number To: " + lRecordNum);
                        modifyLinkedRecordNumber(recordNum, lRecordNum);
                    }
                    break;
                case "n":
                    // Do what N is suppose to do... 
                    String varName = getVariableName(recordNum);
                    System.out.println("Modifying Variable Name To: " + varName);
                    modifyVariableName(recordNum, varName);
                    break;    
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unknown Assignment for Modify (" + 
                            params[0] + ")! Modify Failed!");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void doDelete(String[] args) {
        int recordNum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
            // Split the parameter name and its value
            String[] params = args[i].split(" = |= | =|=");
            // Process Parameters
            switch (params[0]) {
                case "r":
                    // Do what R is suppose to do...
                    // Is the supplied value Numerical?
                    if (params[1].matches("\\d+")) {
                        // Yes...convert to integer
                        recordNum = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
                        if (deleteRecord(recordNum)) {
                            System.out.println("Record Number " + recordNum + 
                                               " has been Deleted.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "y":
                    // Do what Y is suppose to do... 
                    boolean doDel = false;
                    if (params[1].equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                        if (deleteAllLinksTo(recordNum)) {
                            System.out.println("All Links related to Record Number " + 
                                                recordNum + " have been removed.");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!params[1].equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                        System.out.println("Unknown Boolean argument supplied for Y "
                                + "parameter of the DELETE function (" + 
                                params[i] + ")! Link Deletion Failed!");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Unknown Assignment for Delete (" + 
                            params[0] + ")! Delete Failed!"); 
            }
        }
    }

    private static void clearHistory() {
        // A method to clear all history.
        //Code goes here........
    }

    private static void displayRecord (int recordNum) {
        // A method to display a specific record.
        //Code goes here........
    }

    private static String getVariableName(int recNum) {
        // A method to get variable name for a specific record.
        String varName = "";
        //Code goes here........
        return varName;
    }

    private static void modifyLinkedRecordNumber(int recordNum, int newLinkedNum) {
        // A method to modify the liknked record number for a speciic record.
        //Code goes here........
    }

    private static void modifyVariableName(int recordNum, String varName) {
        // A method to modify the Variable Name for a speciic record.
        //Code goes here........
    }

    private static boolean deleteRecord (int recordNum) {
        // A method to Delete a speciic record.
        //Code goes here........
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean deleteAllLinksTo (int recordNum) {
        // A method to Delete ALL Links to the supplied record.
        //Code goes here........
        return true;
    }

}
```